# Changing slick slider dots style depending on slick-active class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

For the past couple of days I've been Googling and searching for solutions and have read a ton of manuals, but I'm still struggling somewhere. And yes, I'm a beginner.

So what I want to achieve is to change Slick slider dots  depending on the `<li class="slick-active">` element class. I've tried many options and if I'm right I need to work with `on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide)`.

[What it look right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suw7e.png)
[What I want it to look(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYzDk.png)
[What I want it to look(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8NUo.png)

I want that when you load the page, the first slide (the active one having `<li class="slick-active">`) has an SVG circle with countdown in it while others have a fully colored circle without the countdown. The countdown timer is set the same as the slides' speed (`autoplaySpeed: 4000`), so when it goes from 00 to 04, the next slide displays.

```js
    jQuery(function ($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        // Slider and slider dots
        $(".banner-slider").slick({
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: false,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 4000,
            dots: true,
            customPaging : function() {

                if ($(".slick-dots > li.slick-active")) {
                    return '<a class="dot">' + '<div id="countdown"> <div id="countdown-number"></div> <svg> <circle r="18" cx="20" cy="20"></circle> </svg> </div>' + '</a>';
                }
                else {
                    return '<a class="dot">' + 'fully colored circle without timer in it' + '</a>';
                }
            }
        });

            var countdownNumberEl = document.getElementById('countdown-number');
            var countdown = 0;

            countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;

            setInterval(function() {
                countdown = ++countdown >= 4 ? 0 : countdown;

                countdownNumberEl.textContent = '0' + countdown;
            }, 1000); });
```

All those `return` statement tags are styled in an `.scss` file and `<div class="banner-slider"></div>` has PHP code in it.

If I run the function as it is written now, I get the countdown circles for all my slides. If i use `if ($(".slick-dots > li").hasClass(".slick-active"))`, it returns `false` in `console.log()`

So, I'm guessing that I need to use the previously mentioned function `on('beforeChange/afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide)`, but I can't figure how to get it to work.

Comment: this seems to be a css issue so please can you create a [mcve] with your current html and css - not sure why you would need js to do any of this - surely you would just style your li with coloured in circle and then override that if it has a class of slick-active to show your svg

Comment: Yes i'm aware of that, but how then I can execute my countdown timer?